# Adjectival step by step

Tags: grammar, orthography, hyphenation, compound-adjectives

When used as an adjective, is it *step by step* or *step-by-step*?

Example,

> Thank you for this step by step guide.

or

> Thank you for this step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Wiktionary, [step by step](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/step_by_step) is the adverbial form, whereas [step-by-step](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/step-by-step) is the adjectivial. So your second example is the correct one.